# meromorphic continuation of Mellin transform

Tags: complex-analysis

Let's say I have a Mellin transform of $f(x)$ to $F(s)$, and the transform converge for $Re(s)>\alpha>0$. If $H(s)$ is a meromorphic function on $Re(s)>0$ with simple poles at $Re(s)=\alpha$, and $F(s)=H(s)$ for $Re(s)>\alpha$. Can we say $F(s)$ has poles on $Re(s)=\alpha$? More specifically, does $F(s)$ has a Laurent expansion $\frac{a_{-1}}{s-\alpha-it}+...$ where $\alpha+it$ is the location of poles?

Answer (score 2):

If $H(s)=F(s)$ for $\Re(s)>\alpha$ and $H$ is meromorphic on an open $U$ containing $\Re(s)\ge \alpha$ then sure $H$ is the meromorphic continuation of $F$ to $U$.

You can say that $F$ has some poles on $\Re(s)=\alpha$ even if to be pedantic (no need to be..) you should say "the meromorphic continuation of $F$ has some poles on $\Re(s)=\alpha$".

Comment: So the Laurent expansion valid?

Comment: Sure the Laurent expansion of $H(s)$ at $\alpha+it$ gives you a series for $\int_0^\infty f(x)x^{s-1}dx$ valid for $\Re(s)>\alpha,|s-\alpha-it|<r$ with $r$ such that $H$ is analytic on $\{ s\in \Bbb{C},0<|s-\alpha-it|<r\}$.